# Calendar on RoR (FullCalendar) not working after gem updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, fullcalendar

FullCalendar stopped working after I upgraded some gems. I needed to add 'google-api-client' to the Gemfile and the Bundle Install process gave me the following message:

```
itsjustme@rubberroom:~/Projects/FunnyFarm$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    faraday (0.8.0)

  In Gemfile:
    google-api-client (>= 0.5.0) ruby depends on
      faraday (~> 0.8.1) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Following instructions, I issued a Bundle Update. This was the result:

```
itsjustme@rubberroom:~/Projects/FunnyFarm$ bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.....
Error Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API
Fetching full source index from https://rubygems.org/
Using rake (10.0.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.3.7) 
Using activesupport (3.2.3) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.3) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.3) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.12) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.3) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.3) 
Using activeresource (3.2.3) 
Installing addressable (2.3.2) 
Installing extlib (0.9.15) 
Installing autoparse (0.3.2) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using bundler (1.2.2) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.2.3) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using multipart-post (1.1.5) 
Using faraday (0.8.4) 
Using jwt (0.1.5) 
Installing launchy (2.1.2) 
Installing signet (0.4.3) 
Installing uuidtools (2.1.3) 
Installing google-api-client (0.5.0) 
Using haml (3.1.7) 
Using httpauth (0.2.0) 
Using jquery-rails (2.1.3) 
Using libv8 (3.3.10.4) 
Using mobilepronto (0.3.2) 
Using mysql2 (0.3.11) 
Using oauth (0.4.7) 
Using oauth2 (0.6.1) 
Using rails (3.2.3) 
Using sass (3.2.3) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using sorcery (0.7.13) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.6) 
Using therubyracer (0.10.2) 
Using uglifier (1.3.0) 
Your bundle is updated! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem
is installed.
```

Neither CSS nor jQuery files were modified and, being new to RoR, I have no idea where to start looking for a solution.

#### Screenshots

This is a screenshot taken before the update:
http://pic.twitter.com/85gUGSg3

This one, after the update:
http://pic.twitter.com/rYvIhsbe

#### Files

The view is too simple to make a difference. But here it is, anyway (show.html.haml):

```
%h4 Agenda dos Médicos
#calendar
```

Similarly, the controller is almost empty. It just points to the view.

```
class WorkSchedsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_login
  def show
  end
end
```

The magic of it all happens thanks to fullcalendar.js, configured as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    eventSources: [
      // Dr. John Doe
      {
      url: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/userthis%40gmail.com/private-blah/basic',
      color: 'dodgerblue'
      },
      // Dr. Jane Doe
      {
      url: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/userthat%40gmail.com/private-blah/basic',
      color: 'brown'
      },
      // Code abbreviated
      {
      ...
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

For the sake of completeness, this is the Gemfile, before the adding 'fullcalendar-rails' (as suggested by Mr. Durrant):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sorcery'
gem 'mobilepronto'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'haml'
gem 'sass'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Seems the table which sets the calendar has been flattened.
Can anyone help? Give some pointers or something?

Comment: It seems to me your bundle update command has finished with no complains . What happens after that , what exactly brakes ? "Doesn't work" is so undefined .... What was your stack before and after update , why you've updated , what they say in the gem's wiki ?

Comment: You are right. I am sorry the question ended up vague. I forgot to post the screenshots but they are available now. The bundle indeed finished without complains but something in the gems installed or updated broke my calendar. The model, the controller, the jQuery for FullCalendar and respective CSS files were _not changed_ in any way. The stack before was basically the same, minus the newly installed gems (requirements of the one I actually needed) and I had to upgrade because I need to use the said gem. I hope this explains it further.

Comment: I've tried to see your uploads , but I get a message :{"processing_time":1,"error":{"error_code":10,"error_message":"Missing Api Key","request":"/v1/image/check_access","query_str":"image_id=814:nscf.png"},"success":false} . Probably you'll have to upload them anywhere else . The more important matter is what are your error messages or the bug is only the browser output ?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, Qumara. I updated the question with new addresses for the screenshots (uploaded to TwitPic). As per your question, that is the problem: I get nothing! No errors whatsoever. It is just the browser that doesn't show what was there before. I, of course, had backups and the backups still show the calendar. Clicking on the buttons mês/semana/dia (month/week/day) **sometimes** gives me a squished grid, but even that is not a guaranteed result (!!!). I am baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see on your screenshots , it reminds me of the nightmare I had in the hot summer days . I have added a class in the .css.scss file , but forgot to close it (one little '}'). No matter I've tried it was a pain and sorrow in various tempos .

In your case I would focus in searching for inconsistent stylesheet , related with the tag "tbody" . It seems all the other css and js are OK . Keep us updated , sir .

Comment: Thank you again, Qumara. I will try replacing the css files, though I find it difficult to believe a Gem would modify the contents of said files. Weird. :\

Comment: We will not give up . I fight with a bear up to 3 times :) . I am about to look at full_calendar's wiki and bug tickets .

Comment: I've looked for what caused the crash . What if you remove the new added gem google-api-client ?

Comment: Thank you, Qumara. I hope that is just an expression and there are no real bears in Bulgaria. :) I need the google-api-client Gem. I am using it to post appointments to Google Calendar. I tried removing the gems (**bundle clean --force**) and updating (**bundle update**) the outdated ones (**bundle outdated**) but still no luck. I might have to look for a FullCalendar replacement. :\

Comment: The problem was solved as suddenly as it happened. I trid so many things I cannot say what actually solved. Perhaps it was reordering the CSS and JS files. I am glad it was resolved though I will have to accept the 'ctrl-alt-del' solution, i.d. it is fixed and I do not know why. Thanks to both Qumara and Michael.

Comment: It's great , the magic of writing code. One more bear tamed .